# How do I get the real usable resolution

Tags: java, swing, window, size

With

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()`

I get the screen size.

But usually this isn't the available size I have for my own program, because on the mac there is a menubar on top and on the bottom an iconbar. Windows also has an iconbar. So how do I get the real available space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Java forum](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=749059):

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Rectangle bounds = ge.getMaximumWindowBounds();
```

Now you have the bounds sans platform-dependent desktop decorations. I don't have a Mac around so I only verified that it works on WinXP/JDK6.

Note that if you auto-hide taskbar, the bounds do NOT include taskbar, which is correct.

Comment: @Geoffrey This has the side-effect of changing the Look and Feel of the application, correct? Is this necessary? I don't understand what effect it has on the local `GraphicsEnvironment`.

Comment: @muffin I think they're just telling you to put the `GraphicsEnvironment` part after look and feel

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try the GraphicsConfiguration/GraphicsDevice instead. You might not be able to get a bounding box that discount the dock on OS X since the area of the dock is still considered screen space. I can move windows on top of it. I can also move the dock to be on the side and not at the bottom of the screen (same goes for the Windows task bar).

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html

Comment: My answer is just one tiny step forward from this.